# Problem in package algorithmic

Tags: algorithmic

This is my code :

```
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE Sort increasingly the $a_{i}, i=1,...,n$
\STATE $a_{n+1}\gets \infty$
\STATE $m \gets 1$
\STATE $\Tilde{x} \gets \infty $
\WHILE{$ \Tilde{x} \geqslant a_{m+1} \mbox{ and } m \leqslant n-1$} \do
\STATE $\Tilde{x} \gets \mbox{ solution of } \sum_{i=1}^{m} \left(  \frac{(x-a_{i})^{+}}{h_{i}}  \right)^{p} = \mathcal{C}^{p} \mbox{ with p=1 or 2 }$
\STATE $m \gets m+1$
 \ENDWHILE  
 \STATE $\Bar{x} \gets \Tilde{x}$
\end{algorithmic}
```

I want to get the new line in the two instructions of while and also adding a caption.
thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the `\Tilde` command?

Comment: please extend your code fragment to complete but small document, which we can test.

Answer (score 1):

Is it something like this you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} \usepackage{algorithm, algorithmic}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My funny algorithm}
\label{fun}
  \begin{algorithmic}
\STATE Sort increasingly the $a_{i}, i=1,...,n$
\STATE $a_{n+1}\gets \infty$
\STATE $m \gets 1$
\STATE $\tilde{x} \gets \infty $
\WHILE{$ \tilde{x} \geqslant a_{m+1} \mbox{ and } m \leqslant n-1$} %\do
\STATE $\tilde{x} \gets \mbox{ solution of } \sum_{i=1}^{m} \left( \frac{(x-a_{i})^{+}}{h_{i}} \right)^{p} = \mathcal{C}^{p} \mbox{ with p=1 or 2 }$
\STATE $m \gets m+1$
 \ENDWHILE
 \STATE $\Bar{x} \gets \tilde{x}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @abdelkarimlamghari If Bernard's answer solves your issue, you should upvote and accept his answer.

Comment: i try that; but they show me :  Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.